# Using a Function parameter a variable to hold a dataframe

Tags: python, function

I am trying to assign new_df the dataframe but it says that new_df is not defined. is there a way that I can assign dataframe to the new_df variable using a function.

```
`def concat(file_xlsx, "sheet1", new_df):
         for f in file_xlsx:
             data=pd.read_excel(file_xlsx,"sheet1")
             new_df=pandas.Dataframe.append(data)
         return new_df`
```

Comment: How are you creating the `Dataframe` that will be passed into the function?

Comment: What is x in your function? You have a for loop over that (presumably iterable) object.

Comment: I edited x out with file_xlsx. So, file_xlsx is a list excel workbooks. I am trying to join them to create a complete dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# create an Empty DataFrame object 
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

def concat(file_xlsx, "sheet1", new_df):
    for f in file_xlsx:
        data=pd.read_excel(file_xlsx,"sheet1")
        # and then append data into it
        new_df=pandas.Dataframe.append(data)
        return new_df
```

You are appending data into a data frame without creating a data frame. First, you need to create a data frame(can be an empty data frame) and then append data on it. Please take a look into the above code snippet by me.